# ¿ Como arreglo elementos del footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de poner la barra de redes sociales en el footer pero no hace el efecto deseado, como la barra de arriba del ejemplo. Se queda como encasillada en una caja. Si elimino `<li class="social_icons clearfix">` funciona, pero se descolocan los elementos del footer.
¿Como podria solucionar? Gracias
Dejo ejemplo hecho en codepen : [Ejemplo mas vistoso](https://codepen.io/miguelitolaparra/pen/LeXrRv)

```css
body {
 background: #2f3133 url(../images/patternbg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.row_4 {
 padding: 30px 0 81px;
 background: #ffffff;
}
p {
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 color: #adadad;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #474848;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 35px 0;
}
.select-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
.isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0s;
}
/* End: Recommended Isotope styles */
/* disable CSS transitions for containers with infinite scrolling*/
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 -moz-transition: none;
 -ms-transition: none;
 -o-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}
.pad_bot3 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
#container {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.containerExtra {
 margin-left: -30px;
}

/*--------links------------*/
.btn-link4 {
 color: #474848;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.btn-link4:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
 transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.pad_bot2 {
 padding-bottom: 43px;
}
.links p {
 margin-bottom: 28px;
}
/*-- contacts page --*/
.gmap {
 margin-top: 7px;
}
.map {
 overflow: hidden;
 line-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
}
.map iframe {
 width: 100%;
 height: 393px;
 border: none;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
.address h2 {
 padding-bottom: 35px;
}
address {
 margin: 8px 0 0 0;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.info {
 font-family: 'Arial', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
}
.padding_top1 {
 padding-top: 31px;
}
.info > p {
 font-family: 'Arial', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.info > p span {
 font-family: 'Arial', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 width: 94px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.info a {
 color: #adadad;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.info a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eb5368;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
/***** contact form *****/
.contact-form {
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
 z-index: 1;
 margin: 0 0 0;
 top: 0;
}
.contact-form .txt-form {
 display: none;
}
.contact-form .coll-1, .contact-form .coll-2, .contact-form .coll-3 {
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 float: left;
 width: 192px;
}
.contact-form .coll-3 {
 margin-right: 0;
}
.contact-form .coll-4 {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.contact-form fieldset {
 top: 13px;
 border: none;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}
.contact-form label {
 display: block;
 min-height: 45px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
.contact-form .message {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
.contact-form input {
 padding: 9px 14px 8px;
 margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #adadad;
 background: transparent;
 outline: none;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}



/*-------privacy_page--------*/
.privacy_page h2 {
 padding-bottom: 42px;
}
.privacy_page p {
 margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.privacy_page .m_bot4 {
 margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.privacy_page a {
 color: #adadad;
}
.privacy_page a:hover {
 color: #eb5368;
}
/*--- content end ------*/
/*--------- footer --------- */
footer {
 padding: 64px 0;
 background: url("../images/linefooter.jpg") top center repeat-x;
}
/*--------------social----------------*/
.social_icons {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 position: relative;
 margin: 28px 0 0;
 z-index: 10;
}
.social_icons > li {
 float: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 32px;
 height: 31px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-right: 14px;
}
.social_icons > li a {
 width: 32px;
 height: 31px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.social_icons > li a img {
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
}
.social_icons > li a:hover img {
 position: relative;
 top: -31px;
}
.footerlogo {
 text-align: center;
}
.smalllogo2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}
.footerpriv {
 margin-top: 21px;
 margin-right: 66px;
 text-align: right;
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #f2eee5;
}
.footerpriv a {
 font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #f2eee5;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.footerpriv a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #eb5368;
}
.share-fb{
    background-color: #2d609b;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-twitter{
    background-color: #00c3f3;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-google-plus{
    background-color: #eb4026;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-linkedin{
    background-color: #0074a1;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-pinterest{
    background-color: #ca212a;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-tumblr{
    background-color: #36465d;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

/**************** footer end ***************/
/*----- media queries ------*/
@media (min-width: 1220px) {
.contact-form .coll-1,  .contact-form .coll-2,  .contact-form .coll-3 {
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 float: left;
 width: 243px;
}
.contact-form .coll-3 {
 margin-right: 0;
}
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 31px;
}
.list3 li figure {
 margin-right: 53px;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 46px;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: 270px;
}
.container {
 padding: 0;
}
}
/**************************************************/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.contact-form .coll-1,  .contact-form .coll-2,  .contact-form .coll-3 {
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
.reserve_table {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.reserve_table figure {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 float: none;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.reserve_table figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.reserve_table .m_bot2 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footercol {
 float: left;
 width: 33%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footerpriv {
 margin-top: 21px;
 margin-right: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.footerpriv a {
 font-size: 14px;
}
.row_4 {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.row_4 .chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.row_4 .row4_col {
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 33%;
}
.list3 {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.list3 li {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
}
.list3 li figure {
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 0;
 padding: 20px;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: 165px;
}
.list1 li a p {
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 22px;
 padding: 24px 0 21px;
}
.nav-collapse_ .nav > li {
 float: left;
}
.navbar_ {
 width: auto!important;
 overflow: visible !important;
 height: auto;
 clear: none;
}
}
/**************************************************/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.row_4 .row4_col .btn-link3 {
 font-size: 12px;
}
.contact-form .coll-1,  .contact-form .coll-2,  .contact-form .coll-3 {
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
.reserve_table {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.reserve_table .m_bot2 {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.reserve_table figure {
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
}
.footercol {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}
.social_icons {
 display: inline-block;
}
.footerpriv {
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 float: none;
 text-align: center;
}
.row_4 {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.row_4 .chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.row_4 .row4_col {
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 30%;
}
.box1,  .box2,  .box3 {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto 25px;
}
.box1 figure,  .box2 figure,  .box3 figure {
 width: 100%;
}
.box1 figure img,  .box2 figure img,  .box3 figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.box2 figure img {
 height: auto;
}
.listbox1 {
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.listbox2 {
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.listbox3 {
 padding-left: 15px;
}
.list1 {
 text-align: center;
}
.sf-menu {
 display: none !important;
}
.select-menu {
 display: block !important;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #343434;
 background: #343434 !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}
.select-menu option {
 padding: 0;
}
}
/**************************************************/
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.row_4 .row4_col .btn-link3 {
 font-size: 18px;
}
.reserve_table {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.reserve_table .m_bot2 {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.reserve_table figure {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 float: none;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.reserve_table figure img {
 width: 100%;
}
.row_4 {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.row_4 .chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 15px 5px 0;
}
.row_4 .row4_col {
 margin: 0;
 float: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
}
/**************************************************/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.list3 li figure {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.list3 li .info1 {
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
}
/**************************************************/
@media (max-width: 360px) {
.chef figure {
 padding: 0;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
}
/*Core variables and mixins*/
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}


/**** Style de buscador google  ***********/


/*
Created by Alejandro Palacios https://github.com/AlexSoicalap
*/

.share-buttons-row{
    height: 40px;

 display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.share-buttons-row >div:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
    border-radius: 100px;
  }

.share-buttons-row > div {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin-right: .3em;
 padding: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
}

/* Style para transicon de carga*/
.loader-page {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 25000;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.loader-page::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid rgb(50, 150, 176);
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, 0);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, 0);
    animation: rotarload 1s linear infinite;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

@keyframes rotarload {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

.loader-page::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, .5);
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, 0);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(50, 150, 176, 0);
    animation: rotarload 1s ease-out infinite;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/compartir.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header id="header">
</header>
<!--content-->
<div id="content">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 chef row4_col">
                    <h2>Comparta nuestra idea </h2>
                 <div class="share-buttons-row">
              <div class="share-fb"></div>
              <div class="share-twitter"></div>
              <div class="share-google-plus"></div>
              <div class="share-linkedin"></div>
              <div class="share-pinterest"></div>
              <div class="share-tumblr"></div>
             </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 footercol">     
                <li class="social_icons clearfix">
                     <div class="share-buttons-row">
                        <div class="share-fb"></div>
                        <div class="share-twitter"></div>
                        <div class="share-google-plus"></div>
                        <div class="share-linkedin"></div>
                        <div class="share-pinterest"></div>
                        <div class="share-tumblr"></div>
                     </li>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 footerlogo footercol"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tm-scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Se resolvio el problema Miguel?

Comment: Perfecto @ManucoBianco , le di un 'margin-left: 25px;' si no se salía por la derecha. Muchas gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el div tiene tan solo `40px` para poner tus iconos. 
Prueba de cambiar en el css lo siguiente:

```
.share-buttons-row{
    height: 100px;
```

Te adjunto el [link de codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZrexR?editors=1100).

Comment: Perfecto @MaucoBianco, solo que hace lo mismo el botón izquierdo en la parte izquierda, si tiene facil solución y puedes ayudarme...??

Comment: claro, justo después de lo anterior, agrega un pequeño margin de 40px. Algo como `margin-left: 40px;`